# How to force the buttons in bottom navigation to be at the bottom in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to use bottom navigation but the buttons or icons appears in the middle not in the bottom, I have use drawer navigation in the same activity i.e. I declare a drawer layout in the xml resource layout.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="168dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:menu="@menu/drawer"
      android:layout_gravity="start">


     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

The code of this activity:

```
package com.example.welcome.madrasti;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    Intent intent1;

    private DrawerLayout d;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle a;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:

                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_home:

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        d = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        a= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,d,R.string.open,R.string.close);

        d.addDrawerListener(a);
        a.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        intent1= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);


        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(a.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){

                   return  true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Is there any idea ?. I have got the bottom navigation as follows : [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/rsaj4mms62w9siu/29831346_423321348112165_210253674_o.png)

Comment: Are you able to see the Hello text?

Answer (score 0):

Changing padding at the Bottom to small a value like:

```
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
```

Also your BottomNavigationView appears to be a square of 168dp size. Is this intentionally? Change the height it or view its layout bounds. It may be very big by itself like a square.

Comment: set gravity and layout gravity to bottom...This is the best alternative..@SoSo